# What is the order of evaluation for function arguments in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

According to my tests it is always left-to-right

```
>> console.log( console.log(1), console.log(2) );
1
2
undefined undefined
```

but I can't find the relevant section confirming this in the ECMAScript standard.

Comment: Does this not follow the order of `,` and grouping by `(` & `)` ? [Operator Precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) ...

Comment: console.log(1), console.log(2) are arguments and functions that are getting invoked like a self executing function

Comment: One might consider that `f(g(0), g(1))` is pretty much guaranteed to do the same thing as `f.apply(thisObj, [g(0), g(1)])`. It's probably a useful mental device to consider the two equivalent, and perhaps it makes more sense to the OP that array elements be defined in left-to-right order.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

All the operators in JavaScript evaluate their operands left-to-right, including the function call operator.  First the function to call is evaluated then the actual parameters in left-to-right order.

[Section 11.2.3](http://es5.github.com/#x11.2.3) is the relevant spec section.

> **11.2.3 Function Calls**
>
> ...
>
> 2 Let *func* be *GetValue(ref)*.
>
> 3 Let *argList* be the result of evaluating *Arguments*, producing an internal list of argument values (see 11.2.4).
>
> ...

and you can see that the *ArgumentList* production is left-recursive

> **11.2.4 Argument lists**
>
> ...
>
> The production *ArgumentList* : *ArgumentList* `,` *AssignmentExpression* is evaluated as follows

and *ArgumentList* is evaluated before *AssignmentExpression* in the following verbiage..

Under EcmaScript 3 some of the comparison operators (`<`, `<=`, `>`, `>=`) evaluated right to left since `a<=b` was defined in terms of `!(b<a)`, but that was widely recognized as a spec error, major interpreters did not implement it that way, and it was fixed in EcmaScript 5.

From the language spec:

> [11.8.5 The Abstract Relational Comparison Algorithm](http://es5.github.com/#x11.8.5) # Ⓣ
>
> The comparison `x < y`, where `x` and `y` are values, produces `true`, `false`, or `undefined` (which indicates that at least one operand is `NaN`). In addition to `x` and `y` the algorithm takes a Boolean flag named *LeftFirst* as a parameter. The flag is used to control the order in which operations with potentially visible side-effects are performed upon `x` and `y`. **It is necessary because ECMAScript specifies left to right evaluation of expressions.** The default value of *LeftFirst* is true and indicates that the `x` parameter corresponds to an expression that occurs to the left of the `y` parameter’s corresponding expression. If *LeftFirst* is false, the reverse is the case and operations must be performed upon `y` before `x`. Such a comparison is performed as follows:

Comment: @ŠimeVidas, the function call operator.  `()`

Comment: *"All the operators in JavaScript evaluate their operands left-to-right."* That's just not correct. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence There are plenty that evaluate right to left.

Comment: @RightSaidFred: Associativity only determines wether you disambiguate `a op b op c` as `((a op b) op c)` or `(a op (b op c)`. It has nothing to do with wether a or b is evaluated first in `a op b`

Comment: @RightSaidFred, you are confusing associativity with order of evaluation.  Associativity is taken into account at parse time, but order of evaluation is significant at runtime.

Comment: @RightSaidFred, to make this clear, try running `var x = 1; (x = [])[0] = x;`.  `x` is now an array that contains itself, not an array that contains `1` because the `x = []` was evaluated before the right-most `x`.

Comment: I see what you're saying. Processing... I didn't downvote you, but the vote may have been my fault, so +1

Comment: @RightSaidFred, meh, downvotes are a fact of life.  I appreciate the question.  To help you process, associativity is why `x = y = z` is the same as `x = (y = z)` but `1 - 1 - 1` is `(1 - 1) - 1` instead of `1 - (1 - 1)`.

Comment: @MikeSamuel: Thanks for the examples. Yes, I understand the associativity end of it, but a incorrectly assumed that expression evaluation followed the associativity. Your Array example clarified that perfectly. Thanks again!

Answer (score 13):

It's defined here:

> The production `ArgumentList : ArgumentList , AssignmentExpression` is
>   evaluated as follows:
>
> 1. **Let `precedingArgs` be the result of evaluating `ArgumentList`.**
> 2. **Let `ref` be the result of evaluating `AssignmentExpression`.**
> 3. Let `arg` be `GetValue(ref)`.
> 4. Return a List whose length is one greater than the length of `precedingArgs` and whose items are the items of `precedingArgs`, in
>      order, followed at the end by `arg` which is the last item of the new
>      list.

**Read here:** http://es5.github.com/#x11.2.4

When a function is invoked, the passed-in arguments are evaluated from left to right.

Comment: Which, enables evaluating statements such as `func(a++, ++a, a *= a, a--, --a)`. It is _defined behavior_ thanks to the specification above, unlike the C language. It's not a good practice, though.

Answer (score 7):

For historical interest, also see section 4.2 [Evaluation Order](http://hepunx.rl.ac.uk/~adye/jsspec11/expr.htm) of JavaScript 1.1 Language Specification (Brendan Eich, C. Rand Mckinney, 11/18/96).

> In a function or constructor call, one or more argument expressions
>   may appear within the parentheses, separated by commas. Each argument
>   expression is fully evaluated before any part of any argument
>   expression to its right is evaluated.