# Does JavaScript have a defined order of evaluation for function parameters?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the order of evaluation for function arguments in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8405989/what-is-the-order-of-evaluation-for-function-arguments-in-javascript)

If I run the following code in Chrome, the parameters to the anonymous function are evaluated left-to-right:

```
(function () {})(console.log(1), console.log(2));
```

Is this defined in the specification or is it implementation-defined?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is part of the ECMAScript 5 documentation:

> Let  names  be a List containing, in left to right textual order, the  Strings corresponding to the identifiers of FormalParameterList. If no parameters are specified, let names be the empty list.

Source: http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf (Pg 99)