# Is a containing function executed before its arguments?

Tags: javascript

I'm confused about the order of evaluation in JavaScript. In my first example, I expected the parameter `number++` to be evaluated before the function `console.log()`, making the console output `2,3,4`.

Prints `1, 2, 3` to the console:

```js
    var foo = [1,2,3]
       for (number of foo) {
         console.log(number++)
       }
```

Prints `2, 3, 4` to the console:

```js
    var foo = [1,2,3]
       for (number of foo) {
         number++
         console.log(number)
       }
```

From my understanding of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8405989/what-is-the-order-of-evaluation-for-function-arguments-in-javascript), the arguments would be evaluated first from left to right before the containing function is executed. This doesn't appear to be the case - can someone please explain why not?

Comment: `variable++` adds after it has been outputed/used, `++variable` before. None of both would be a function call

Comment: Don't forget do declare all variables, like `number`, or they end up in the global scope. Or check out [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) where it will throw if you try to access/assign an undeclared variable.

Answer (score 2):

The issue here is with the ++ operator. This says take the value of number, pass it to the function and then add one to the number.

If you change it to ++number, you will get the expected behaviour. This says add one to the value of number and then pass that to the function.

Answer (score 1):

This is the basics of `pre-increment` and `post increment`. Remember we have `++number` and `number++`. `++number` increases number immediately (at that point), while `number++` increases number the next time it comes across number.

Comment: Thank you! So simple now it's explained. I come from a Ruby background and just beginning to learn JavaScript. Ruby has no increment operators, which is probably why I didn't spot this.

Comment: `number++` *returns* the old value, `++number` *returns* the new value. They both still increment number **at that point** and *not* (somehow magically) the next time they are come across.

Answer (score 0):

`console.log(number++)` runs `console.log(number)` because it can not run the ++ after as parameter correct would be `console.log(++number)`

```js
var foo = [1,2,3];

for (number of foo) console.log(number++);

console.log("---");
for (number of foo) console.log(number);

console.log("---");
// This is the same as your second block of code
for (number of foo) console.log(++number);
    
console.log("---");
// You can see that does not change the foo values
for (number of foo) console.log(number);
```